# Video playback tethered to scroll choppy only with 1920x1080 videos

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I have a video that I want to play based on the user's scroll position (as the user scrolls, the video plays; when the scroll stops the video pauses).

This works fine with most mp4 videos, however when I try to us a video that has a 1920x1080 resolution the playback is "choppy", only updating the video image once the user is done scrolling (mouseup) and not during the scroll (mousedown).

Here is an example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3beyxot/). The default video in the example has a resolution of 1920x1080. The commented video link is 1280x720 and works fine. This happens with every 1080 video tested. 1920 width is preferred because the video in the finished product should be full-screen-width and should cover most desktop screens without losing much resolution quality.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
    <div id="main-wrapper">
  <video id="main-video" width="auto" height="240" controls preload>
    <source src="http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/jellyfish-25-mbps-hd-hevc.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <!--
  <source src="http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/star_trails.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  -->
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 var myContent = $('#main-video');
 var myContentConainter =$('#main-wrapper');
 var vid = document.getElementById("main-video");
 var originalTop = 0;
 var scrollPos=0;
 var atTopState = false;


 var vid = document.getElementById("main-video");
 var videoToHeightRatio= .012;
 var videoLength;

vid.onloadedmetadata = function() {
      videoLength =vid.duration;
 };

 vid.pause();


document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){

    ////// Set up variables ////////


    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    var windowMidPoint = ($(window).scrollTop()) +( $(window).height() / 2 );


    var contentTop = $(myContent).offset().top;

    var contentBottom = contentTop + $(myContent).height();

    var contentMidpoint = contentTop + ($(myContent).height()/2);



    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

    //Video stuff



    var currentSec = vid.currentTime;


    var videoContainerOverlow = videoLength/videoToHeightRatio;

   var containerHeight = $(window).height();

   var newContainerHeight = containerHeight + videoContainerOverlow
   myContentConainter.css('height',newContainerHeight+"px");



    if (windowTop >= contentTop){
        if (atTopState==false){
          originalTop = contentTop;
          myContent.css("position","fixed")
          myContent.css("top","0")
         }

      vid.currentTime = (windowTop / videoContainerOverlow) * videoLength;

     atTopState = true;

    }

    if(  windowTop < originalTop){
       myContent.css("position","unset")
      myContent.css("top","unset")
      atTopState=false;
    }

     if (windowBottom <= contentTop){
      myContent.css("position","unset")
      myContent.css("top","unset")
      atTopState=false;
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#main-wrapper{
  background-image:linear-gradient(blue,red);
  height:300vh;
}
#main-video{

}
```

Comment: this is probably a sign of your GPU struggling to keep up - what GPU are you using?

Comment: Does the example work for you? This issue occurs on each device I've tried. Ideally this should work for the average user.

Comment: The example works I don't see it choppy (on Radeon Pro 555X 4 GB)

Comment: I have a GTX780 and it's choppy as......bro

Comment: as someone who hates even waiting for "wallpaper" to load, I find this appalling, even if it were smooth, didn't kill performance/smoothness, didn't hog bandwidth and battery, and didn't make the page take forever to finish...